# How to output to a file when conditions are correct with mouseclicked and itemlistener

Tags: java, if-statement, jcheckbox, mouseclick-event, itemlistener

What I am trying to do is output to a file when you press Save.  They have 4 checkboxes and they need to choose one.  when they choose one it will tell the program which one they choose and output the following accordingly.

What I have currently does not work, any ideas?

```
JButton buttonSave = new JButton("Save");
        buttonSave.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

                String name = whoSoldTo.getText();
                String test = sellPrice.getText();
                int soldToPrice = Integer.parseInt(test);

                checkboxMint.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
                    }
                });

                if(ev.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    write.soldToFile(name, "mint", soldToPrice);
                    System.out.println("Mint works");
                }

                checkboxTobacco.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                            write.soldToFile(name, "tobacco", soldToPrice);
                        }
                    }
                });

                checkboxFruit.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                            write.soldToFile(name, "fruit", soldToPrice);
                        }
                    }
                });

                checkboxCreme.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                            write.soldToFile(name, "creme", soldToPrice);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        buttonSave.setBounds(227, 143, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(buttonSave);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write all the itemlisteners on their own i.e outside the mouseclicklistener. Declare global boolean variables for the different items e.g Bool fruits that's set to false and when an event happens in an itemlistener set it to true. In the onMouseClicklistener check which boolean variable is true and do the action associated with the item

Comment: I just got rid of the save button altogether and am just sticking with the checkboxes.